What components will I require to ascertain the capacity of a lithium iron battery?
I see quite a few posts on measuring battery capacity. However, I cannot find one that shows how this is practically achieved (if there is a post, kindly inform me).
I am assuming in order to ascertain the capacity I would need the voltage and current that is flowing to the load (using a shunt). In addition, I would require a micro-controller to use these two parameters to calculate the capacity.
How would I therefore use these two parameters in order to determine the battery's capacity?
Do I need other parameters as well, if so what will there be?
I want to determine the "actual" capacity for a 12V 8Ah and 18Ah lithium battery.

The actual battery capacity depends on multiple factors, such as how full you charged it to begin with, how fast you will discharge it, and how empty you let the battery before stopping the measurement.
You can use microcontrollers or other ICs, such as coulomb counting battery management ICs, or simply a progammable electronic load.
Capacity is the amount of charge Q you get out in amp-hours. As you say you have 8 Ah and 18 Ah batteries, they must be of that rated capacity under some conditions they were specified to have.
If you don't know what the conditions for the measurements were, you will get a different capacity under some other conditions.


Do I need other parameters as well, if so what will there be?

As for different conditions, The Influence of Temperature on the Capacity of Lithium Ion Batteries with Different Anodes contains:

Changes in temperature directly affect the discharge performance and discharge capacity of a lithium ion battery

Looking a some sample graphs in that report, the Relative reference point capacity can vary from say 36% to 123% as the ambient temperature was changed from -40 °C to 60 °C. The actual variation depends upon the battery chemistry.
